# Why am I getting ClassCastException when I instantiate a class and casting it to that interface which is being implemented by this class?

Tags: java

I am new to this `ClassLoader` concept. I wasted almost a week for this but I couldn't find any solution.

```
URLClassLoader jarLoader = new URLClassLoader (urlList);
Class clazz = jarLoader.loadClass(classname);
Object instance=clazz.newInstance();
(Interface1)(instance);
```

Here, in line 4, I'm getting `ClassCastException`.

Please help me resolve this? I would appreciate for any feedback.

Comment: could you please post the actual exception here?

Comment: between before casting you could use if(instance is Interface) check to check if this instance is really of type you are casting to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface1 might have been loaded by a different class loader than you class. Classes are considered different when loaded by different class loaders.

Comment: but i m adding it into the same class loader

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like `Interface1` is loaded by two different class loaders. You are casting it to `Interface1` (A), but your jarLoader wants it to be `Interface1` (B).

Are you sure that `urlList` doesn't contain the URLs of previously loaded classes? Or a different version of `Interface1`?

This will help you find the error (use this instead of `(Interface1)(instance);`):

```
Class<?>[] interfaces = instance.getClass().getInterfaces();
for (Class<?> interfaceType : interfaces) {
    System.out.println("---------");
    System.out.println(interfaceType);
    System.out.println(interfaceType.getClassLoader());
    System.out.println(
        interfaceType.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
}
```

Comment: in my scenario i have a list of urls and in this list i am loading 2 different jars.one jar contains implementing class and other jar contains that interface.so is this the

Comment: hey, i tried to use code..but here also i am getting class cast exception..what to do now?:(

Comment: @mum whoa, you really seem to have messed up your classloaders :-)

Answer (score 2):

that's probably because of Interface1 has been loaded by the different classloader.

Comment: Hi, maybe you should try this: Debug the following statements: Interface1.class.getClassLoader() and then instance.getClass().getClassLoader() - if you see that the classloaders totally different - your issue would be resolved

Comment: BTW. I assume that (instance instanceof Interface1) is resolved to eb  true otherwise the ClassCastException is trivial :)

Answer (score 0):

Then use the constructor that takes another classLoader as argument - pass the class loader associated with the interface.

```
URLClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(urlList,Interface1.class.getClassLoader())
```

The problem in your case is that the class is implementing the interface loaded by the URLClassLoader where as you are trying to cast it to the interface loaded by a different class loader.

Comment: in my scenario i have a list of urls and in this list i am loading 2 different jars .one jar contains implementing class and other jar contains that interface.so is this the problem??

Comment: If you use the above code - the Interface will be loaded from the same classloader - the one in which you are executing this piece of code. The Interface in the jar provided in the urllist is ignored - you can even exclude that.  That is because the classloader will delegate to the parent before it tries to load it.  The URLClassLoader when it needs the interface it will delegate the request to the parent classloader (which was passed as argument). This will ensure that only one version of the Interface exists. Try the code and let me know if it doesn't work.